# Pass a string from Windows Context menu to clickonce application

Tags: c#, contextmenu, clickonce

I am creating a small program to do some file renaming through a right click in windows explorer.

I am trying to pass the folder name of a right clicked folder to a clickonce application that hasn't been opened yet.

I would like the application to launch with the folder path filled into a textbox.

Where exactly in my code to I catch this incoming data.

I know I can launch the program through "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\"Appname"\command" with the %1 modifier, but where does that argument come out on the other end?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Well, this renaming program is already in use, and is a little involved. It already a standalone working Windows Form Program. So at the moment, I am trying to figure out how to launch it with arguments, specifically the foldername that it was launched from. I dont really have relevant code to show you, because I'm not sure where this code should go. That's the problem. I dont know what/where to look to hand the program arguments as its starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get arguments passed to ClickOnce applications use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;`

Comment: And the Activation data should include the string that is passed because of the %1 modifier?